# Преобразование из int в char. Создание одномерного динамического массива

Tags: c++

```
void FunctionChar_Line() {
    int digit, k = 0, i=0;
    cin >> digit;
    int a = digit;


    while (a > 0) {
        a = a / 10;
        k++;
    }   
    vector <char> string (k+1);
    while (i != k) {
           while (digit > 0) {
                  int mod = digit % 10;
                  digit = digit / 10;
                   string[i] = mod;
                   i++;
           }
    }
    i = 0;
    while (string[i] != '\0') {
        cout << string[i];
        i++;
    }

}
```

Реализую преобразование числа в строку - не работает. Думаю, проблема с неправильным созданием массива. Подскажите, как лучше создать массив для строки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте заменить

```
string[i] = mod;
```

на

```
string[i] = '0'+mod;
```

Да и цикл развернуть надо...

Если уж не годится `string`, а позарез нужен именно `vector<char>`, то вот вариант:

```
void FunctionChar_Line()
{
    int digit;
    cin >> digit;

    vector<char> s;
    while (digit > 0)
    {
        s.push_back('0' + digit%10);
        digit /= 10;
    }
    for(int i = s.size()-1; i >=0; --i)
    {
        cout << s[i];
    }

}
```

Comment: хм.. сработало..Спасибо огромнейшее. цикл разверну = )

Comment: Посмотрите дополнение в ответе. Ну и если ответ устраивает - помечайте как принятый...

Answer (score 0):

Я бы делал так:

```
void FunctionChar_Line()
{
    unsigned int digit;
    cin >> digit;

    sting s;
    while (digit > 0)
    {
        s = ('0' + digit%10) + s;
        digit /= 10;
    }

    cout << s;

}
```